# Table with multiple form and just one form is working

Tags: jquery, html

I use Jquery to append my table, when i append it, a new tbody is added and each tbody contain a form. The problem is that onley the first form is working i don't know why. This is my script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#tr_clone_add").click(function(){

    $('#listuser').append('<tbody><form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/insertMovement" method="post" commandName="movement"><tr>'+
'<td><form:input type="text"  path="nom_etabl"/></td>'+
'<td><form:input type="text" class="tcal" readonly="true" path="date_fin"/></td><td><input type="submit" value="" class="button round blue image-right ic-right-arrow"></td></tr></form:form></tbody>');
     f_tcalInit();
     });
});
```

Where is the problem ?

Comment: What happens? What do you mean when you say it isn't working? Is there an error message? Does the page just sit there? Does it post but the values are missing? Etc.

Comment: the action of the form must insert data to database, but when i click on the button nothing is happend

Comment: `<form:form` and `<form:input` looks like server side scripting to me. You can't add such pseudotags with javascript.

Comment: Is this ASP.NET MVC with Razor? Or is this all supposed to be happening client-side in Javascript?

Comment: that's java with spring mvc framework. I run the application in the server tomcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding pseudotags (`<form:form>` and `<form:input>`) that are normaly parsed by the server and translated to valid HTML directly to the DOM tree. The browser can't handle them, so your form doesn't work.

You have two options:

1. add valid HTML markup (`<form>` and `<input>` instead of the pseudotags
2. use an AJAX call to parse the markup on the server and add the resulting HTML to your DOM tree.

You'll have to decide what's better suited for you, depending on what the server generates from those tags.

Comment: Come now, an ajax call just to generate form markup? I don't think that is a valid suggestion.

Comment: I believe if the `<form:input>` tag adds more properties to the tag on generation (for example a unique ID to distinguish between multiple forms or tags) this is a valid solution.

Comment: Perhaps, but I'd say that will need some workflow optimization, worst case scenario - print the id into a hidden field and snag it with JS by the field's id. Not saying that an ajax call does not have a valid use scenario, I'm saying that it has to be justified. An ajax call generates a lot of connection overhead.

Comment: The first solution is not valid for me, because every request is sent to spring controller ... and i have no idea to do it by ajax .. :(

Comment: Can i use AJAX to append the table ? if i do like this it can work ? @GeraldSchneider

Comment: The only thing you would use AJAX for is to have your server translate `<form:form>` to `<form>` tags. It has nothing to do with appending the table. And that is only nessecary if your server adds more properties to the tags, but without seeing more code we can only speculate. If your server side code doesn't add anything nessecary it would be far easier to directly add valid HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Your form html is invalid. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp) for the right way to do it.

Comment: why it's not valid? form:form is a spring tag. and i just copy  the first one (which is writen outside the script in the jsp page) and past to the the script to have a similar form.

Comment: You are adding the form via JavaScript (read: client-side). The format you are using, I assume, is valid in the syntax your server-side script parses, but not to client browsers. Sorry, I am unfamiliar with either java or spring (I'm php), but you can be sure that when adding via client-side js, this will not work.

Comment: Replace <form:input type="text"  path="nom_etabl"/> and <form:input type="text" class="tcal" readonly="true" path="date_fin"/> with valid HTML markup per the example I provided in the answer. Sorry, no specifics, I can't understand what your markup implies.

Comment: You are no longer working with spring. Spring is server-side. Spring finished working, returned the resulting html and js to the client browser and stopped. After than the client browser parses the js, the js adds form nodes to your DOM, and then can't figure out what those forms mean.